# Cucumber Testing js.erb functions when no html.erb exists

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

My rails application is using js.erb views instead of html.erb views for specific windows. This works fine in practice, but when I'm using cucumber tests with capybara it gives me an error of

```
Missing template admin/groups with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml],    :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
```

When I click the button pertaining to this particular view. There is no groups.html.erb but there is a groups.js.erb. I want to somehow tell cucumber/capybara to not try to render the groups.html.erb but still render the groups.js.erb. I would prefer not to generate an unnecessary html file to render the same thing the escape javascript below is doing.

groups.js.erb:

```
$("#admin_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'groups') %>");
```

Relevant admin controller method:

```
def groups
    @groups = Group.all
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use proper MIME type handling for your responses. Try this:

```
def groups
  @groups = Group.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

eventually you can be more specific about how to respond :

```
format.js { render layout: false }
```

more info on respond_to [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to).

**note:** if your controller only manages js responses, you can add `respond_to :js` at the top of the class, and then use `respond_with @object` in your actions.

Comment: this helps a bit, with this cucumber no longer demands to see html but it still won't properly render the escape javascript, that's a different question though so this is the right answer

Comment: if you take a look at [escape_javascript source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript), you'll see that the method checks if its argument is marked `html_safe`, and marks output accordingly. if the ouput is not marked html_safe, it wont render correctly. Try this : `<%= raw j(render partial: 'groups') %>` (`j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`)